# Python: writing list of list in a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of list with this elements:

```
listes = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]
```

I used to this code for writing my csv:

```
with open("result.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(listes)
```

The result:

```
a;b
c;d
e;f
```

**But** **i would like**:

```
a;c;d
b;e;f
```

Thanks

Comment: huh, I can make no relation to your input and output. Do you mean you would like 'a;c;e' en 'b;d;f' ?

Comment: no, i would like 'a;c;d' en 'b;e;f'

Comment: how would the writer know what you want. You should feed it correctly... (So recreate arrays for the writer)

Comment: In my question, there is the desired result...

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your list and write to file

```
with open("result.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(zip(*listes))
```

Comment: Why the `map()` call?

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction not sure if writerows operates on sets as well. Casted it to list for safety

Comment: `zip()` returns list of tuples in Python 2 not set and it'll work in Python 3 as well where zip returns an iterator.

Comment: your code returns 'a;c;e' en 'b;d;f', but i would like 'a;c;d' en 'b;e;f'